# Vue: Interpolating a dynamic number of props?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a dynamic component that the parent can pass in data to shape it.  I am stuck on how to interpolate the index as part of passed in prop. I assume it's possible but I think I'm just interpolating it incorrectly.

**// Parent**

```
<div>
   <BoxComponent
      :numberOfBoxes=3
      boxTitle0="Hi"
      boxTitle1="Foo"
      boxTitle2="Test"
   >
   </BoxComponent>
</div>
```

**//BoxComponent**

```
   <div v-for="(box,index) in numberOfBoxes">
       <div class="title">
           {{boxTitle + ${index}}} <-----
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Have you considered refactoring it to accept an array instead?

Comment: not a bad idea.  I can just make an array of objects that contain 'title', 'body' and other data I need

Answer (score 1):

Like @yuriy636 also proposed, I would suggest you pass an array of objects named "boxes".

If you assume `boxes` looks like this:

```
[
 {title: "Hi"},
 {title: "Foo"},
 {title: "Test"}
]
```

You can simply do this:

**// Parent**

```
<div>
   <box-component :boxes="boxes"/>
</div>
```

**//BoxComponent**

```
   <div v-for="box in boxes">
       <div class="title">
           {{ box.title }}
       </div>
   </div>
```